# bcrypt.compare cb is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I'm using passport-local and I've already hashed my passwords in my mongo database. I can't figure out why my bcrypt.compare() isn't working correctly. It says 'cb is not a function' but it is. I just saved the callback as a variable in the same file instead of saving it in my User schema. Anyone ran across this problem before or see any errors in my code??

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
User.findOne({ username: username }).exec().then((user, err) => {
if (err) return done(err)
if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' })

const comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, hashedPassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hashedPassword, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err)
    return cb(null, isMatch)
  })
}
 comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
   if (err) return done(err)
   if (!isMatch) return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' })
   return done(null, user)
 })
})
}))
```

Comment: Why are you using that separate `comparePassword` function at all (instead of calling `bcrypt.compare` directly)?

Comment: This is unrelated, but for security purposes you generally shouldn't differentiate between bad username and bad password. Just return a same generic message, that way a malicious user won't know if they found a valid username or not. That's my 2 cents anyway.

Comment: I can't get it to work with just bcrypt.compare either :/

Answer (score 1):

So after hours of struggling with bcrypt.compare, I just decided to clear out my database and create new users from scratch. I ended up using bcrypt.compareSync() and it finally verified my passwords! So make sure you have all of your methods defined on your model BEFORE you add users/whatever to your database. I thought I had already added the compare function but I guess I was wrong. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error, just reinstall `npm and bcrypt`, be careful! see what version of node you are working that is also important. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something like this before. It has to do with async handling and the fact that all your code is already in the .then() handler of a promise (user.findOne()). It's generally not a good idea to mix promises and the callback pattern.

What I ended up doing is wrapping my comparePassword function in a promise and then including it in the promise chain. My code was quite different, but in your case it would look something like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {

function comparePassword(candidatePassword, hashedPassword) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hashedPassword,
    (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      else if (!isMatch) reject(new Error('Incorrect Password'));
      else resolve();
    });
  });
})

User.findOne({ username: username }).exec()
.then((user, err) => {
if (err) return done(err)
if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' })
return comparePassword(password, user.password)
})
.then(/*do stuff if password is a match*/)
.catch(/*do stuff iff not a match*/)
}))
```

You could also try to just

```
return comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
```

at the end of your .then(), and I'd declare comparePassword outside of the .then() like in my code above.

Answer (score -1):

The code looks alright to me. Eventhough I didn't test it.

Does your password comparison has to be aSync? Have you considered using bcrypt.compareSync?

Example:

```
MyPasswordTool.prototype.validateHashedPassword = function(challlenger, hashedPassword) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(challlenger, hashedPassword);
};
```

Comment: For clarifications, please [add a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824613/bcrypt-compare-cb-is-not-a-function-error#).